# Need Help to Understand Regular Expression Immediately

Tags: regex, perl

Can anyone explain the meaning of the `Regular Expression` pattern below in `Perl`?

```
s/^(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/$1,$2/
```

Comment: It adds a `,`  before the last 3 digits. Please make some effort before you ask questions which you can solve by little research on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the string:

```
-1234567890
```

Using the regex pattern:

```
s/^(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/$1,$2/
| | |  |    | | |    |
| | |  |     \|/     replace pattern using groups [1],[2]
| | |  |     [2] match a digit [0-9] (3 times)
| | | [1] match a digit between one and unlimited times
| |[1] matches character "-" literally between zero and one time [greedy]
| ^ assert position at start of the string
substitution pattern
```

Using the original string above would become:

```
-1234567,890
```

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/gV9kE9/1